# How to use vector path as a guide to snap to, in Adobe Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I tell Adobe Illustrator CC not to edit an existing path when I draw over that path? I want to use a path as a guide to snap to, but I don't want my new vector to start extending/editing that path-guide I'm drawing over.

To clarify the question more. When I draw a vector, and I want to draw a second vector starting with the anchor point of the existing vector, then Illustrator always starts extending the first vector, instead of keeping the first and second vector separate.

Comment: Either right click the path and choose Make Guides.. or Lock either the Path or entire Layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways.

1. you can select the path you want to use as a guide and lock it by pressing cmd+2 (object>lock>selection). While it is locked you cannot alter or select the path but it will still respond to smart guides. It can be unlocked with cmd+alt+2(object>unlock all)
2. you could also move the path to a new layer and then lock the layer.